# Необходимость запятой и согласование

Tags: пунктуация, согласование

Нужна ли запятая после "мысли" в предложении "Когда дело, вернее, мысли доходили до Гефестиона, всё тонуло в алом мареве"? И правильно ли согласование глагола "доходили" с предыдущим словом, "мысли", если основным существительным является "дело"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. *Мысли* - подлежащее, а *доходили* - сказуемое. Запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится.

> И правильно ли согласование

Правильно. Согласовываем именно с *мыслями*, которые являются "более верным" вариантом.

> если основным существительным является "дело"

Тогда зачем перебивать это существительное словом "мысли", указывая, что последнее является верным? В такой конструкции предложения именно слово "мысли" является основным существительным.

Comment: oleedd, я думала, что "вернее, мысли" является дополнительным смыслом, как уточнение. Но Ваши мысли кажутся мне вернее)))

Comment: Так и есть. Но дальше нужно уже и отталкиваться от этого уточнения. Вот здесь есть такой же пример - предложение про письмо: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_265 И ещё такой момент. Как-то дело и мысли вообще не соотносятся. Всё равно, что муху уточнить через слона)))

Comment: Да, это, скорее, не уточнение, а противопоставление)

Comment: "Вернее" как вводное всегда указывает на уточнение. Противопоставление образуется частицей "не" и союзом "а" или тире: *не дело дошло, а мысли*. Нашёл сам текст - пунктуация там такая же. Но смысл этого предложения всё равно неясен. "Тонуть в алом мареве" - какой-то фразеологизм. В общем, такое можно наблюдать, когда человек что-то перепутал: *принеси мне яблоко, вернее, апельсин*. Возможно, что здесь это приём "умышленной ошибки", как иногда на сайтах перечёркивают текст.